# jQuery tablesorter sorting comma separated numbers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery Tablesorter 2.0 (http://tablesorter.com/docs/).
Sorting numbers is working fine, but as soon as I add

```
number_format($count);
```

to my code, the sorting is not working anymore.
It sorts like this:

> 810,208 -> 7,671,897 -> 2,329,439

instead of

> 7,671,897 -> 2,329,439 -> 810,208

Any way to fix this? I need the comma separated number for better reading.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.christianmontoya.com/2008/11/14/extending-jquery-tablesorter-to-support-comma-delimited-numbers/

```
jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "fancyNumber",
  is: function(s) {
    return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
  },
  format: function(s) {
    return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
  },
  type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: How would this look if the numbers are formatted like `1'300'000`, with just quotes?